# Install jupyter despite pin-1 not installable because it requires python 3.12

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, miniconda, python-3.11

Attempting to install jupyter with `conda install jupyter`, from an Anaconda prompt, raised `pin-1 in not installable because it requires python 3.12`

I have python 3.11 installed, and the version I installed of miniconda uses python 3.11.

Any other way to install jupyter?

Full error traceback:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package jupyter-1.0.0-py27_4 requires python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ jupyter is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

Comment: Hi. Curious if you were able to solve this and how?

Comment: Despite the user claim of this being Python 3.11, Conda is clearly being run in an environment with `python=3.12` installed. Jupyter wasn't built yet for Python 3.12 and since Conda will not change Python versions without explicitly being told to do so, the solve fails. OP could improve this post by providing `conda list -n env python` for the environment and include in the post the full shell interaction, starting from `conda install -n env jupyter` (not just the error message). Otherwise, this post is unfortunately inconsistent.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
    conda install python=3.10
```

then, rerun this command:

```
    conda install jupyter
```

Comment: Could you maybe make it clear why choosing to roll back Python 3.11 to 3.10 would help?

Comment: No need for two commands. `conda install python=3.10 jupyter` would suffice. Also, OP's error message indicates Python 3.12 is installed. So, `conda install python=3.11 jupyter` would also work.

Answer (score 4):

just install python with version between 3.10 - 3.11 in your environment

i've just fix this issue with this command
first:

conda install python=3.10

then:

conda install jupyter

Comment: Have you considered that rolling back Python 3.11 to 3.10 was not the only way? What pointed you to this method?

Answer (score 2):

Have you observed that the Anaconda default *base* environment contains a lot you will never use, yet add complexity to package compatibility, whenever you want to add something.

Instead, **creating a minimal environment**, with just what you need, will save you some time (and switch to JupyterLab - it is time).

In addition, this will leverage conda's **environment solver**, that will ensure compatilibty between your essential packages. Use commands like these:

```
conda create -n yournewenvname python jupyterlab
```

After environment activation, this one, for instance, lets you run jupyterlab right away. Tested today, it installed:

> conda list python  # python 3.11.7

> conda list jupyterlab # jupyterlab 4.0.8

Now if you wish to maintain **Python version 3.11 and jupyter**, then use this instead:

```
conda create -n yournewenvname python=3.11 jupyter
```

This raised no conflict, and installed:

> conda list python  # python 3.11.7

> conda list jupyter # jupyter 1.0.0

This indicates that rolling back your Python to an earlier version such as 3.10, as other answers suggested, is in fact not required.

---

Managing your minimal environments is key to good practices and reproducibility of calculations.

References:

- The essential [Conda cheat sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)
- Anaconda docs: [environments management and activation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it by installing packages using **conda-forge**. Just type the following command in **Anaconda Prompt**:

```
conda activate yourEnvName
```

then install the desired packages using **conda-forge**. Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```