# I couln't install Jupyter using conda command

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter, miniconda

[I try setup a conda envirnment using miniconda but I couldn't setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/migEF.png)

I need a solution to this, I search trough internet , but i didn't get solution yet.

## 1st step

```
(base) C:\Users\Nabee\data_science\ml>conda create --prefix ./env pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

and I got this error,

```
(C:\Users\Nabee\data_science\ml\env) C:\Users\Nabee\data_science\ml>conda install jupyter
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package jupyter-1.0.0-py27_4 requires python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0, but none of the providers can be instad
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ jupyter is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

Comment: New answer and I'll welcome your feedback in your own time. 
Why install Jupyter in a seperate step in an environment you have just created? (and why stick to Jupyter instead of moving on to Jupyterlab?)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue when trying to install CNVkit under freshly created env. I created new env with python 3.11 but it didn't help. Finally I've downgraded python to 3.10.13 and it started working. (BTW make sure you added all conda channels that you need)

Comment: What made you think this method for CNVkit would be valid for Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77508384/pin-1-in-not-installable-because-it-requires-python-3-12-when-i-was-trying-to), and my problem has been solved:

```
conda activate some_env
conda install python=3.11
conda install -n some_env jupyter
```

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547758) suggests, Python with version between 3.10 - 3.11 are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You first create a new environment, then want to install Jupyter on top of it right away. What made you opt for not including Jupyter in your initial environment requirements, at the time of creation ? Doing so leverages the conda environment solver to figure your optimal configuration:

```
# your requirements plus Jupyter 
conda create -n testenv pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn jupyter
```

This proceeded without error and installed:

> conda list python # 3.10.13

> conda list jupyter # 1.0.0

etc..

So if you want to stick to Jupyter (as opposed to moving on to JupyterLab), indeed it looks like you should keep your Python at 3.10, but with this method, you can know it for yourself, instead of having to ask for advice.

Generally, attempting to install a (slightly old) Python module *after* the environment has been created (with up-to-date modules) may cause such problems. Related because same type of problem and solution: [Install jupyter despite pin-1 not installable because it requires python 3.12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77508384/12846804)