Unable to import pandas from Spyder editor
I use Spyder and seek to import databases from various formats including a .csv file. Unfortunately, import pandas as pd appears with a warning red symbol next to it.
How can I correct this problem?
I have made sure Spyder and pandas are in the same environment. From the Anaconda prompt:

conda list pandas returns Pandas 2.1.4 version
Similarly I get Python 3.1.1

What else is possible to  fix this error?

Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. I am very new with these programs. I am using Anaconda navigator and spyder. Do I have to download python? or do you mean spyder(python)? if so, the version that I have of spyder (python 3.11) and Pandas is 2.1.4. How can I know if they are compatible?

Red symbol, ok, but what error does it raise if you still run the import line?

Problem solved?

You'd probably need to ensure compatibility of your versions of Python, Spyder and Pandas. Downloading compatible modules for you is conda's job, that is why one good way to clear that question is to start fresh with a new environment using conda from an Anaconda prompt.
Give your new environment a name and specify the desired minimal set of modules:
conda create -n your_env_name python spyder pandas numpy matplotlib seaborn

Followed by environment activation:
conda activate your_env_name 

Then, back in Spyder, imports such as import pandas as pd will function as expected.
Why?

Doing so leverages the conda environment solver, which will ensure compatibility of all requested modules, and Anaconda will do all the downloading for you.
You won't need a vast majority of the modules preinstalled in the conda default environment anyways
Based on your choice of tags, I had initially assumed you wanted compatibility with Python 2.7. It would have probably fetched you Python 2.7.18, the latest Python 2 release
Pandas requires numpy,
matplotlib and seaborn in case you anticipate to draw plots

Do look up that other answer for useful references including conda cheat sheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77982405/12846804

make sure to Update Spyder and its dependencies using this commandes
conda update spyder
conda update anaconda
if not installed make sure to install pandas
conda install pandas

There is no such thing as conda update anaconda. Where did you find this?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@OCa of course there is, see the very first code block here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Well, yes. Have you tried it yourself? It comes as a surprise that you would recommend to update Spyder before updating Anaconda, unlike how to update spyder on anaconda. What is the point?
