# pin-1 is not installable because it requires python 3.12.*

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, miniconda

While using miniconda to try and install jupyter notebook in my env, I get this message:

> pin-1 is not installable because it requires
> python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.
>
> Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
> python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')

But when I check python version:

> (c:\Users...\env) C:\Users...>python --version
> Python 3.12.1

I'm trying to learn how to set up an environment and open jupyter notebook. I was following along with a tutorial and it worked fine the first time. But I'm trying again and getting this message. I am following the exact same steps I took yesterday when it worked.

Comment: Sorry. I'm really new to this.  I typed "pip install jupyter". I don't know what that means yet, but it worked. Lol

Comment: You may not have changed anything but the source about pin and versions allowed did. Anyway, this seems addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77508384/8508004) if you happen to be using Conda, which I don't think you are? But others getting here may.

Comment: So you think you got past that issue by trying `pip install jupyter` now? That is good.

Answer (score 0):

pip install jupyter

that worked.